# Convert a technical conflict into HR case

Tags: work-environment, conflict, relationships, leadership, conflict-resolution

I have one conflict that is dressed as a technical issue which I believe is an actual HR issue. Involved in the technical conflict resolution are the project manager and the department lead.

But the technical conflict has not been resolved for 2 months. Everyone is pretending it is a technical difference while I believe, based on the complete lack of progress, it is pretty much a HR thing.

I have heard many times the term “To involve HR”. I have noticed that most Project managers are always turning to avoid placing issues as a HR problem.

My question:

1. What does it mean to Involve HR?
2. Should I be afraid to speak directly that in my opinion the problem is no longer technical, but a HR issue?
3. What can I expect if I go this way?
4. The fact that the department lead is involved- does it mean informally it is already a HR issue?
5. Who should I contact to make the HR issue?
6. What if my colleagues continue to pretend it is technical?

I should clarify that I am on the recipient END Of the escalations.

Comment: Maybe you should explain what the actual conflict is about?

Comment: What makes you think HR should be involved? If you or your coworkers are being harassed by one (or both) of the disagreeing parties, maybe. If it's just about work not being done (due to conflicting instructions or whatever), you might want to ping upper management instead. But really, without details it's hard to say.

Comment: Is this related to your previous post?

Comment: @KingDuken It is difficult to explain the problem in first place. Also the other side is manipulative and changes the problem all the time in order to raise the alarm a meeting and than switch back to the original problem. The problem is technical yrs, but at one point the way the meetings are forced it becomes NON technical.

Comment: The problem roughly is what key should be used to access data. And how to USE external key to access data on remote system and somewhere there is mixed the business requirment to be able to correlate two ordets in two different systems.

Comment: The person escalating me is cobol developer isfront Of retirment with zero knowledge Of java. Or modern microservices and so on. The developer does not make difference between surrogate key and natural key.

Comment: Actualy the developer does not Even develop. Does only testing.

Comment: @KingDuken Yes.

Comment: @KingDuken agreed I will delete it :)

Answer (score 3):

What I'm gleaning from your question is that a difference of opinions about a technical matter has not resolved for a few months and this is putting the project behind.  The answer to whether this is an "HR issue" is a simple no.  HR doesn't resolve management issues relating to the work (with the possible exception if there is a law or regulation being violated, but even in that case you should have a compliance or legal department to go to).  It does exist to resolve inter-employee conflicts, but that's when those conflicts are about some kind of unprofessional conduct, like bullying.  If two employees are having a professional disagreement about a project, it's up to management to make a decision about which way to go, not HR.

Assuming I've read your question correctly, at this stage your best bet is to make sure your management is aware of your opinion that the technical disagreement needs to be resolved and the project needs to move on.  Keep in mind that this may mean that management takes the other person's side, but that's life, the project can then move forward.

Based on your comments, it sounds like this coworker is doing some unprofessional things to keep arguing about this issue, but nothing that cannot be handled by your management.  Let your manager know that she's intentionally wasting time arguing about this other issue when scheduling meetings on other things, and if it's impacting your work you can tell her that you aren't going to spend time arguing about the project in question except during the times you've allocated in your schedule to talk about it.  Really though, at this point your management really needs to make a decision and tell you all to live with it.

If this keeps escalating and your management refuses to resolve the issue, you're probably still better off trying to reduce your contact with the coworker and keep written notes about your conflict with her and what she's done to escalate it.  Her trying to manipulate you into arguments about the issue is something HR might be able to mediate, but you usually want to try and resolve your issues first, and at least give your manager a chance to resolve it before going to HR.  There are plenty of other answers on here detailing everything that can go wrong with going to HR, so I'll keep it brief.  Going to HR is like filing a lawsuit against your neighbor - you might get a judgement in your favor, you might not, but your neighbor will never be friendly to you again and the rest of your neighborhood will have their own opinion on whether or not the lawsuit was justified and treat you accordingly.  Sometimes it's your only option, but it comes with a cost.

Answer (score 2):

You're the technical leader. Resolving technical disputes is your job. You should hear all the arguments, make a decision, and then make it clear to all concerned that the decision is made.

If arguments continue to be raised, and you believe they are without merit, then reiterate that the decision has been made and will not be remade. Remind the argumentative one that your job is to make the decision and you have done so.  Remind (if necessary) the rest of the team that the matter has been decided and they should proceed according to the decision that was reached.

If arguments still continue, then it is the job of your manager to manage the situation.  Take the dispute to your manager.

So, no, it's not an HR issue, at least not until the manager decides that someone needs to be officially disciplined.